# MultiList not showing complete text (Codename One)

Tags: codenameone

Im using a MultiList to display some result from a web service but the address is not showing up completely.

Please this [picture](https://05360592106309013684.googlegroups.com/attach/5f2e26e1e8d5b/address.png?part=0.1&view=1&vt=ANaJVrHBL9AKjXvJ8y7DdUPw9zTQuoQ0rMWaSpzY4BQBjrafiRm1gOm90I8Z1ODygKbN1o9ekJzgMnJD3b7TRIQWQFUNi9i0WSZNQaiEfjxxPEfrdydttkI)

The first address should be "Jalan Gertak Merah, 80000 Johor Bahru, Johor, Malaysia" and not "Jalan Gertak Merah, 80"

How can I correct this please.

This is my code:

```
Style s = UIManager.getInstance().getComponentStyle("Button");
FontImage p = FontImage.createMaterial(FontImage.MATERIAL_PORTRAIT, s);
EncodedImage placeholder = EncodedImage.createFromImage(p.scaled(p.getWidth() * 3, p.getHeight() * 4), false);
f.setTitle("Tourist Attractions");
getattractive();
ArrayList arr = (ArrayList) response.get("results");
for (Object m : arr) {
    Map ma = (Map) m;
    address = (String) ma.get("formatted_address");
    name = (String) ma.get("name");
    icon = (String) ma.get("icon");
    data.add(createListEntry(name, address, icon));
}
DefaultListModel<Map<String, Object>> model = new DefaultListModel<>(data);
MultiList ml = new MultiList(model);
ml.getUnselectedButton().setIconName("icon_URLImage");
ml.getSelectedButton().setIconName("icon_URLImage");
ml.getUnselectedButton().setIcon(placeholder);
ml.getSelectedButton().setIcon(placeholder);
findContainer(f).add(BorderLayout.CENTER, ml);
c.addComponent(bn);
bn.addActionListener((ActionEvent evt) -> {
    System.exit(0);
});
findContainer(f).add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, c);
f.getComponentForm().revalidate();
```

Comment: How do you expect to correct this? Increase the screen size? Shorten the text?

Comment: @ShaiAlmog thanks for your response. what i mean is that is there a way i can reduce the font size and make the text go multiline

Comment: MultiList doesn't support that https://www.codenameone.com/blog/avoiding-lists.html